# Filter column for datepattern in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to filter the dataframe column on the basis of the datepattern so automatically only valid dates format get passed for further operation. The sample code is below

```
    val datePattern = "\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}"

    val df1 = df                           // df is spark.read.csv dataframe
      .filter($"timewithDate".toString.matches(datePattern))
      //othercode
    )
```

But I am getting below error.
***Cannot resolve overloaded method 'filter'***

Can anyone please explain to me what I am doing wrong here and how to correctly resolve the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` method expects a column as first parameter, but you are passing a `Boolean` instead. You can cast a column using `.cast` method but you can not explicitly convert that to string and apply string methods.

To fix your issue, you can use:

```scala
val df1 = df.filter(col("timewithDate").rlike(datePattern))
```

column's `rlike` is the same as string's `matches` in principle.

You can find more about `rlike` [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-rlike-regex-matching-examples/).